# yesterday worked 3g modem, today Ubuntu does not see it

Tags: networking, usb-modem, 3g

Yesterday worked 3g modem, today Ubuntu does not see it.

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick (modem on)
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 019: ID 17ef:0003 Lenovo 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`Bus 003 Device 016: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick (modem on)` It is my 3g modem.

Then I try

`dmesg | grep GSM`

`[   30.516245] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)`

Then I go to `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`

And add string

```
#my megafon 12d1:1446
ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="1446", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Remove and insert the modem, but it still does not work. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something very strange, if switched on and off - it does not work. If a reboot, it also does not work. But if you go on windows, and then again on Ubuntu, it works. It is really some dark magic.